# Haskell's code indentation issue in function's definition

Tags: haskell, layout, syntax-error, mergesort

I was trying to code mergesort in Haskell, but something goes wrong.
I think the following code *should be correct*

```
-- UPDATE : COMPLETE PROGRAMM'S CODE
merge xs [] = xs
merge [] ys = ys
merge (x:xs) (y:ys) 
    | x <= y = x:merge xs (y:ys)
    | otherwise = y:merge (x:xs) ys

mergeSort xs
    | length xs < 2 = xs
    | otherwise  = merge (mergeSort (myleft xs)) (mergeSort (myright xs))
       where myleft xs = take (half xs) xs
             myright xs = drop (half xs) xs
             where half = \xs -> div (length xs) 2
```

Since first where is referred to "otherwise" line it's indented farther than that.
The second where is referred to all the first "where block", so it should be nested in the first one.
When compiling it gives me this error

```
 Variable not in scope: mergeSort
   |
26 |  mergeSort xs
   |  ^^^^^^^^^
```

So there's something wrong with the function's definition.
I tried to fix the layout in many different ways, for example

```
 mergeSort xs
    | length xs < 2 = xs
    | otherwise  = merge (mergeSort (myleft xs)) (mergeSort (myright xs))
    where myleft xs = take (half xs) xs
          myright xs = drop (half xs) xs
          where half = \xs -> div (length xs) 2
```

But none of them works.

I also looked for solution here and I found something which is pretty close to what I was doing --> [Haskell Merge Sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37082925/haskell-merge-sort/52896140)
It also provides a correct code

```
mergeSort merge xs
        | length xs < 2 = xs
        | otherwise = merge (mergeSort merge first) (mergeSort merge second)
        where first = take half xs 
              second = drop half xs 
              half = length xs `div` 2
```

But why does this work? Isn't it needed a second where to specify "half"? Why is it absent?
Can't understand why mine isn't working anyway.

Comment: It looks like you are *calling* mergesort with `mergeSort xs` can you share the full file. Likely there is a syntax error immediately before this.

Comment: Sure, I'll update the question immediatlly

Comment: In the first snippets your `half` is available inside `myright` but not `myleft`, because the second `where` attaches to the definition of `myright`. Also, please don't post code in the comments: rather, edit your question so that it can be properly formatted/indented.

Comment: There's no way i can attach "half" 's definition to both the two lines? Do i have to write "where half (..)" twice?

Comment: See my answer. I will add @chi explanation.

Comment: @FloraAngileri You could use `where` twice, but that would be inconvenient. When you write `where x = something1 ; y = something2 ; z = something3` all the expressions `something1, something2, something3` can see all the variables `x,y,z` (possibly leading to a recursive definition). E.g. `where x=y+2 ; y=7` defines `x` as `9`. The same effect is achieved by `where y=7; x=y+2`, order does not matter. If you need `half` in multiple places, just define it in the same `where` group as done in the last snippet you posted.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I made some other mistake when I tried to compile it with half as the last. Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Now I understand how "where" properly works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code *half* is only "visible" in the *myright* definition.

Removing the second `where` works:

```
merge :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge = undefined

mergeSort :: [a] -> [a]
mergeSort xs
  | length xs < 2 = xs
  | otherwise  = merge (mergeSort (myleft xs)) (mergeSort (myright xs))
     where myleft xs = take (half xs) xs
           myright xs = drop (half xs) xs
           half = \xs -> div (length xs) 2
```